# Как перенести проект C# из Visual Studio в среду gnu/linux?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio

Имеется виндовый проект в visual studio, надо перенести его на дистрибутив ubuntu операционной системы gnu/linux.

Как я понимаю, надо первым делом избавится от windows forms и сделать консольный интерфейс. Это сделаю.

Проблема в том что в проекте используется сторонняя библитотека dll (для подключения и работы с внешней БД mysql) Её можно каким-либо образом перенести или следует искать алтернативу под gnu/linux?

Comment: .NET Core 1.0 (прежнее название .NET Core 5) - для Windows, Linux и OS X.-- см. http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html

Comment: Здоровый nhibernate работает под mono, так что и вашу либу проще запустить и проверить, прежде чем искать альтернативы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как я понимаю, надо первым делом избавится от windows forms

Mono ж вроде имеет свою реализацию Winforms, совместимую по крайней мере процентов на 99. Говорят так.
Что же до WYSIWYG, то в штатной IDE нету его для Winforms, только для GTK#, но можно скачать и поставить MWF Designer.

> Проблема в том что в проекте используется сторонняя библитотека dll

И опять же, как и с Winforms: почему вы уверены, что она не пойдет на Mono?
Библиотека для работы с БД теоретически могла бы хоть на утюге или микроволновке работать, если ОЗУ и ПЗУ хватит. Ничего платформозависимого там не должно быть. (Исключение - ADO.NET и иже с ним, но это не совсем библиотека под .NET, оно завязано на нативном виндовом ADO)
Попробуйте написать MySQLьный хелловорлд на Mono - судя по всему, в вашем случае следует начать с этого.

Answer (score 4):

> Её можно каким-либо образом перенести

если у вас есть исходники, то вы можете попробовать их перенести (это называется «портировать») на другую операционную систему.

> следует искать алтернативу

если нет исходников или их портирование по каким-либо причинам невозможно, то — да, следует искать либо писать альтернативу.

---

по поводу конкретно взаимодействия с сервером *mysql*: у них на сайте лежит [инструкция](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-unix.html), как приделать «костыли».